# Upgraded Ubuntu to 20.04, now external HDD won't mount

Tags: mount, hard-drive, systemd

I upgraded my PC to 20.04 and am finding that I can't mount my external HDD (ext4 formatted) anymore.  It doesn't matter if I choose any of the directories created under `/dev/disk/by-*/*part1` or `/dev/sdb1` (it shows as that in the output of `fdisk -l`).

In journalctl I always just get to see:

```
systemd[1253]: media-seagate_blu_1.mount: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: media-seagate_blu_1.mount: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: Unmounted /media/seagate_blu_1.
systemd[1]: media-seagate_blu_1.mount: Unit is bound to inactive unit dev-di>
kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (nu>
systemd[1]: Unmounting /media/seagate_blu_1...
umount[3462565]: umount: /media/seagate_blu_1: target is busy.
```

Comment: "Unit is bound to inactive unit dev-di" that would assume you need to activate that unit?

Comment: Great idea @Rinzwind .... you wouldn't happen to know how to do that, or where to find that unit file?